# how to specify test cases to run in travis CI

Tags: r, travis-ci

I have travis ci .yml file which run just fine. However, there are couple of test I don't want to run in travis CI. I am using testthat framework in R

How can I specify to run certain test but not all ?

```
language: r
sudo: required
cache: packages

before_install:
  - echo -e "machine github.com\n  login $CI_USER_TOKEN" >> ~/.netrc
  - chmod 755 ./travis-tool.sh
  # - ./travis-tool.sh bootstrap


install:
  - ./travis-tool.sh install_r devtools
  - ./travis-tool.sh install_r testthat
  - ./travis-tool.sh install_r knitr
  - ./travis-tool.sh install_r BH
  - ./travis-tool.sh install_r dplyr
  - ./travis-tool.sh install_r dbplyr
  - ./travis-tool.sh install_r later 
....
```

Comment: Is `testthat::skip_on_travis()` what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, That is what i was looking for thanks !!!

Comment: @Consistency please add your comment as answer. Looks like OP is happy.